# AEM ACS Commons Generic List editor breaks when more than 8 items are added

Tags: java, adobe, aem

**ACS Commons version 5.0.6

AEM version 6.5.8.0**

I am attempting to edit a Generic List in http://localhost:4502/generic-lists.html/etc/acs-commons/lists by clicking the thumbnail and then clicking the "Properties" in the top action bar. This brings me to http://localhost:4502/mnt/overlay/acs-commons/components/utilities/genericlist.html?item=/etc/acs-commons/lists/[path-to-list]. When there are 8 or fewer items already configured in the generic list, the editor page loads as expected and I can update the list. When there are greater than 8 items, a blank page is loaded and I get the following stack trace in my error log:

```
20.07.2021 15:01:56.223 *INFO* [sling-threadpool-26a55c4e-0bfd-42ac-ba57-0ef069a1e5f3-(apache-sling-job-thread-pool)-4-com_day_cq_replication_job_publish(com/day/cq/replication/job/publish)] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish.queue Job for agent publish processed in 2036ms. Failed.
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.taglib.AbstractDispatcherTagHandler.doEndTag(AbstractDispatcherTagHandler.java:128) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.taglib:2.4.0]
    at org.apache.jsp.libs.granite.ui.components.coral.foundation.form.form_jsp._jspService(form_jsp.java:279)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) [org.apache.felix.http.servlet-api:1.1.2]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:502) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    ... 283 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.ProcessorConfigurationImpl.match(ProcessorConfigurationImpl.java:465) [org.apache.sling.rewriter:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterResponse.getProcessor(RewriterResponse.java:170) [org.apache.sling.rewriter:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterResponse.getWriter(RewriterResponse.java:110) [org.apache.sling.rewriter:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.helper.OnDemandWriter.getWriter(OnDemandWriter.java:38) [org.apache.sling.scripting.core:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.helper.OnDemandWriter.write(OnDemandWriter.java:61) [org.apache.sling.scripting.core:2.3.2]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.helper.OnDemandWriter.write(OnDemandWriter.java:61) [org.apache.sling.scripting.core:2.3.2]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:119) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:273) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.helper.OnDemandWriter.write(OnDemandWriter.java:61) [org.apache.sling.scripting.core:2.3.2]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:277) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.helper.OnDemandWriter.write(OnDemandWriter.java:61) [org.apache.sling.scripting.core:2.3.2]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:277) 
[...]
    ... 319 common frames omitted
20.07.2021 15:02:06.105 *ERROR* [[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] [1626807726050] GET /mnt/overlay/acs-commons/components/utilities/genericlist.html HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Uncaught SlingException
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.ProcessorConfigurationImpl.match(ProcessorConfigurationImpl.java:465) [org.apache.sling.rewriter:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterResponse.getProcessor(RewriterResponse.java:170) [org.apache.sling.rewriter:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterResponse.getWriter(RewriterResponse.java:110) [org.apache.sling.rewriter:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.helper.OnDemandWriter.getWriter(OnDemandWriter.java:38) [org.apache.sling.scripting.core:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.helper.OnDemandWriter.write(OnDemandWriter.java:61) [org.apache.sling.scripting.core:2.3.2]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.helper.OnDemandWriter.write(OnDemandWriter.java:61) [org.apache.sling.scripting.core:2.3.2]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:119) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:273) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.helper.OnDemandWriter.write(OnDemandWriter.java:61) [org.apache.sling.scripting.core:2.3.2]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:277) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.helper.OnDemandWriter.write(OnDemandWriter.java:61) [org.apache.sling.scripting.core:2.3.2]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:277) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.helper.OnDemandWriter.write(OnDemandWriter.java:61) [org.apache.sling.scripting.core:2.3.2]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:119) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:289) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.helper.OnDemandWriter.write(OnDemandWriter.java:61) [org.apache.sling.scripting.core:2.3.2]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:119) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:183) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:99) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:71) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.JspRuntimeContext$JspFactoryHandler.releasePageContext(JspRuntimeContext.java:112) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at org.apache.jsp.libs.granite.ui.components.coral.foundation.form.fieldset.fieldset_jsp._jspService(fieldset_jsp.java:189)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) [org.apache.felix.http.servlet-api:1.1.2]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:502) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:339) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:97) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:600) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:388) [org.apache.sling.scripting.core:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:184) [org.apache.sling.scripting.core:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:491) [org.apache.sling.scripting.core:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:552) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.7.2]
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:44) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.7.2]
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:82) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.7.2]
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDeveloperModeFilter.doFilter(WCMDeveloperModeFilter.java:119) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-core:5.12.158]
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.7.2]
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:156) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-core:5.12.158]
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.7.2]
    at com.adobe.acs.commons.granite.ui.components.impl.include.IncludeDecoratorFilterImpl.doFilter(IncludeDecoratorFilterImpl.java:92) [com.adobe.acs.acs-aem-commons-bundle:5.0.6]
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.7.2]
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.filterRootInclude(WCMComponentFilter.java:375) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-core:5.12.158]
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:190) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-core:5.12.158]
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.7.2]
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.page.PageLockFilter.doFilter(PageLockFilter.java:91) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-core:5.12.158]
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.7.2]
    at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:94) [com.day.cq.cq-personalization:5.12.44]
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.7.2]
    at com.adobe.granite.csrf.impl.CSRFFilter.doFilter(CSRFFilter.java:217) [com.adobe.granite.csrf:1.0.20.CQ650-B0002]
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.7.2]
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:283) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.7.2]
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.dispatchRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:323) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.7.2]
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.dispatch(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:211) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.7.2]
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.include(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:104) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.7.2]
[...]
    ... 283 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.ProcessorConfigurationImpl.match(ProcessorConfigurationImpl.java:465) [org.apache.sling.rewriter:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterResponse.getProcessor(RewriterResponse.java:170) [org.apache.sling.rewriter:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterResponse.getWriter(RewriterResponse.java:110) [org.apache.sling.rewriter:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.helper.OnDemandWriter.getWriter(OnDemandWriter.java:38) [org.apache.sling.scripting.core:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.helper.OnDemandWriter.write(OnDemandWriter.java:61) [org.apache.sling.scripting.core:2.3.2]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.helper.OnDemandWriter.write(OnDemandWriter.java:61) [org.apache.sling.scripting.core:2.3.2]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:119) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:273) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.helper.OnDemandWriter.write(OnDemandWriter.java:61) [org.apache.sling.scripting.core:2.3.2]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:277) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.helper.OnDemandWriter.write(OnDemandWriter.java:61) [org.apache.sling.scripting.core:2.3.2]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:277) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.helper.OnDemandWriter.write(OnDemandWriter.java:61) [org.apache.sling.scripting.core:2.3.2]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:119) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:289) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.helper.OnDemandWriter.write(OnDemandWriter.java:61) [org.apache.sling.scripting.core:2.3.2]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:119) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:183) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:99) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:71) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.JspRuntimeContext$JspFactoryHandler.releasePageContext(JspRuntimeContext.java:112) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at org.apache.jsp.libs.granite.ui.components.coral.foundation.form.fieldset.fieldset_jsp._jspService(fieldset_jsp.java:189)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) [org.apache.felix.http.servlet-api:1.1.2]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:502) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
    ... 319 common frames omitted
```

Has anybody experience this issue before? The issue has been raised in GitHub for the ACS Commons project, but no solution has been discovered to my knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my experience this issue happens due to rewriter configurations . Please try removing /apps/myapp/config/rewriter and check if it works fine.

Comment: Thank you for finding the cause! Since this folder has actually in my repo from before the AEM version upgrade, I changed the folder name in CRXDE from rewriter to rewriter-test, saved it in CRXDE, then renamed it back to the original and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Update - Issue with acs commons generic lists having more than 8 items gives 500.

This issue is fixed with ACS-Commons v-5.3.4 and above

https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-commons/commit/5d4de1e8d7e77c880da320a1508a33a9759c6799

Thanks