# Groovy script for "AEM ACS Commons Generic List editor breaks when more than 8 items are added"

Tags: java, spring, adobe, aem

```
renameRewriterFoldersInApps();
protected void renameRewriterFoldersInApps(){
  Session session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
  Workspace workspace = session.getWorkspace();
  workspace.copy(originalNamePath1, renamedpath1)
  workspace.copy(originalNamePath2, renamedpath2)
  Node node1 = session.getNode(originalNamePath1)
  Node node2 = session.getNode(originalNamePath2)
  node1.remove()
  node2.remove()
  session.save()
  revertNamesOfRewriterFoldersInApps()
}

protected void revertNamesOfRewriterFoldersInApps(){
 Session session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
 Workspace workspace = session.getWorkspace()
 workspace.copy(renamedpath1, originalNamePath1)
 workspace.copy(renamedpath2, originalNamePath2)
 Node node1 = session.getNode(renamedpath1)
 Node node2 = session.getNode(renamedpath2)
 node1.remove()
 node2.remove()
 session.save()
}
```

This is the script that I have written to fix the issue but it does not work fine. The proposed solution [AEM ACS Commons Generic List editor breaks when more than 8 items are added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68460284/aem-acs-commons-generic-list-editor-breaks-when-more-than-8-items-are-added)
does work if i do it manually on crx/de
Any idea what is wrong with my script?

Comment: is there any error when you run the script?

Answer (score 0):

ACS Commons Generic List more than 8 items issue is fixed with ACS Commons **v5.3.4**
https://github.com/whitbread-eos/dummy-repo-header/commit/7ccf1f79e54630e0a12e12ffbc145cf022fdbfe5